# How to build a generalized scope that adds a join clause?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to write a "scope" that adds a left join to my queries.

Example usage:

```
$bookings = Booking::where('bookings.company_id','=',Auth::user()->company_id)
    ->withGuid();
```

I've got that working, but I've hardcoded the class name and table name:

#### GuidScope.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause;

class GuidScope implements \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface {

    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  Builder $builder
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder) {
        $builder->macro('withGuid', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->leftJoin('guids', function (JoinClause $join) {
                $join->on('guids.pk', '=', 'bookings.id');
                $join->on('guids.type', '=', DB::raw("'Booking'"));
            });

            return $builder;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Remove the scope from the given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  Builder $builder
     * @return void
     */
    public function remove(Builder $builder) {
        // TODO: Implement remove() method.
    }
}
```

#### GuidTrait.php

```
<?php

trait GuidTrait {
    public static function bootGuidTrait() {
        static::addGlobalScope(new GuidScope);
    }
}
```

How can I remove the hardcoded `booking.id` and `DB::raw("'Booking'")` in GuidScope.php? Is there a way to get the table name and model class name from the `Builder` or `JoinClause` object?

Answer (score 0):

I dug through the source code some more. You *can* do it!

```
public function apply(Builder $builder) {
    $builder->macro('withGuid', function (Builder $builder) {
        $model = $builder->getModel();
        $builder->leftJoin('guids', function (JoinClause $join) use ($model) {
            $join->on('guids.pk', '=', $model->getTable().'.'.$model->getKeyName());
            $join->on('guids.type', '=', Sql::raw('?',[get_class($model)]));
        });

        return $builder;
    });
}
```